# Can Anyone explain why this code does not work?

Tags: regex, perl, modifier

I am trying to do a substitution of some variables into a string.
The hash contains the data, the $name string is the format.
It will put in two of the variable but not the %M one.
I am baffled. I have tried two different signal characters and also
substitutes with and without spaces. The %M does not go in. ????

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %Sub = (A=>'Alan',G=>'42', M=>"Memories of Japan");
print "\%Sub=\n".Dumper(%Sub)."\n====\n";

my $name = "#M #A (#G).epub";
print "$name\n====\n";
$name =~ s/(#([AGM]))/($Sub{$2})/eeg;
print "$name\n====\n";

%Sub = (A=>'Bob',G=>'13', M=>'NightHawk');
print "\%Sub=\n".Dumper(%Sub)."\n====\n";
$name = "%M %A (%G).epub";
print "$name\n====\n";
$name =~ s/(%([AGM]))/($Sub{$2})/eeg;
print "$name\n====\n";
```

Comment: Never mind... Code is wrong.

Comment: `$name =~ s/(%([AGM]))/($Sub{$2})/eeg;` Still won't substitute a string with spaces in it.

Comment: That regex is matching either of `A`, `G`, `I` (`[AGI]` character class) -- no `M` ...?

Comment: Thanks zdim.  I caught that late.  However, the first one still doesn't work with a string with spaces in it.

Comment: Can't write a proper answer now ... (1) no need for `ee` and it can be very dangerous, and here there is no need for even one `e` (2) too many parens ... try this one-liner: `perl -wE'$n = "#M #A (#G)"; say $n; %h = (M => "x", A => "y", G => "z"); $n =~ s/#([AGM])/#$h{$1}/g; say $n'`

Comment: just in case: the "one-liner" above is entered on the command line and hit Enter. Or, take what is in between `'...'` (that's code that `perl -e` executes) and put it in a file and do `perl file.pl`

Answer (score 1):

You have doubled the "e" modifier at regexpr. Additionally, in this example you can delete it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %Sub = (A=>'Alan',G=>'42', M=>"Memories of Japan");
print "\%Sub=\n", Dumper(%Sub), "\n====\n";

my $name = "#M #A (#G).epub";
print "$name\n====\n";
$name =~ s/#([AGM])/$Sub{$1}/g;   #<-- changed
print "$name\n====\n";

%Sub = (A=>'Bob',G=>'13', M=>'NightHawk');
print "\%Sub=\n", Dumper(%Sub), "\n====\n";
$name = "%M %A (%G).epub";
print "$name\n====\n";
$name =~ s/%([AGM])/$Sub{$1}/g;   #<-- changed
print "$name\n====\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```perl
s/.../($Sub{$2})/eeg
```

is a shorthand for

```perl
s/.../eval( ($Sub{$2}) )/eg    # For each match,
                               # execute eval( ($Sub{$2}) )
                               # and use the value returned.
```

You're literally asking Perl to compile and execute the value of `$Sub{$2}` as Perl code, but `Memories of Japan` is not (normally) valid Perl code.

You want

```perl
s/.../$Sub{$2}/eg              # For each match,
                               # execute $Sub{$2}
                               # and use the value returned.
```

or even

```perl
s/.../$Sub{$2}/g               # For each match,
                               # execute qq/$Sub{$2}/
                               # (equivalent to "$Sub{$2}")
                               # and use the value returned.
```

Note that you should *always* use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have caught the problem of treating `NightHawk` as Perl code.